# uploading app to market: android

Tags: android, uploading

Am for the first time uploading my app to google play, which is a paid one! . I have read the documents, but am not quite sure what all will be asked when I start doing it in the console. I have prepared screenshots, short description, noticed size of the app. what else all will be asked while uploading? Can i have a break in between uploading an app? am new to this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't worry. first you upload the app then you can edit everything and only when you feel ready you publish it to the play store

Answer (score 1):

> I have prepared screenshots, short description, noticed size of the app. what else all will be asked while uploading?

All of this is outlined in the [Launch Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html).

> Can i have a break in between uploading an app?

Yes, you can start the process by filling out some of the information, then stop before actually publishing the application. Until you click the "publish" button, your application will not show up in the Play Store.